# Rename the Formatted Author name using vba in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to change the Author name from comments and Formatted using VB Application.

I tried using this code to rename the comments, but it is not changing for Formatted text.

```
Dim objComment As Comment

    'Change all author names in comments
    For Each objComment In ActiveDocument.Comments
        objComment.Author = "Editor"
        objComment.Initial = "ED"
    Next objComment
```

Please check the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the element in the screen shot is not a comment. This is a review change - Revision tracking is on, at least for formatting. If you aren't interested in tracking changes to the document, revision tracking should be turned off and all revisions in the document accepted.

Comment: I need the revision tracking should be on, and i need to mention the formatting and the comments there. I have to update the Authors real name to some other given name, using the script.

Comment: @ram In that case, you'd also need to loop the `Revisions` collection, but I don't know whether it's possible to change the `Author` value for those, you'll need to test.

Comment: I have tried this code,ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

It is converting as a Author, I don;t know how it is changing, Now i need to convert it as Editor.

Comment: `With ActiveDocument
        .ReadOnlyRecommended = False
        .Password = ""
        .WritePassword = ""
        .RemovePersonalInformation = True
        .RemoveDateAndTime = True
    End With`

In the above code  **RemovePersonalInformation** is Removing the real authors name and converting to Author. 

I need to rename the author to Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Sub ChangeCommentAuthor()

```
Dim J As Integer

Dim rNameFind As String
Dim rNameRePlace As String

rNameFind = InputBox("Enter the Reviwer Name to Find", vbOK)
rNameRePlace = InputBox("Enter the Reviwer name  to Replace", vbOK)

If (rNameFind = "") Then
MsgBox "Input Reviwer Name to find is empty"
Exit Sub
End If

If (rNameRePlace = "") Then
MsgBox "Input Reviwer Name to replace is empty"
Exit Sub
End If

For J = 1 To 3

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count

Dim oInitial As String
If InStr(1, ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial, "") > 0 Then
oInitial = Replace(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial, rNameFind, rNameRePlace)
Set objComment = ActiveDocument.Comments(i)
    objComment.Initial = oInitial

End If

Next i

Next J
```

End Sub